# Check if a field is empty while importing data from Excel file in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, if-statement, eloquent

I am trying to import data from excel file into database tables in Laravel. I have successfully imported the data but If I mistakenly leave a field empty then I get error that column cannot be null. So I need check if the all necessary  data is provided.
I use this code.

```
IndependentContractor::create(['staff_id' => $staff->id, 'address' => $excel_row['address'],  'longitude' => $excel_row['longitude'], 'latitude' => $excel_row['latitude'], 'tax_id' => $excel_row['tax_id'], 'business_name' => $excel_row['business_name'], 'person_incharge' => $excel_row['person_incharge'], 'phone_of_person_incharge' => $excel_row['phone_of_person_incharge'], 'general_manager' => $excel_row['general_manager'], 'phone_of_general_manager' => $excel_row['phone_of_general_manager']]);
```

I can use `If()` to check the data but I will have to repeat this in almost 7 places because there are 7 different tables in which data is being stored.
also if statement will look like this.

```
if(!empty($excel_row['address']) && !empty($excel_row['longitude']) && !empty($excel_row['latitude']) && !empty($excel_row['business_name']) and so on )
```

So is there any better way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using looping, using the array_key, assumming database column name = excel column name

example :

```
$data = [];
foreach($excel_row as $key => $value){
  if(!empty($excel_row[$key])){
    $data[$key] = $excel_row[$key];
  }else{
    dd('empty column found'); //your code here
  }
}
//if everything goes fine
IndependentContractor::create($data);
```

Comment: But this $excel_row has other fields for other user and I need to extract fields for other users. anything on that?

Comment: the key is you just need to define which columns available, and not null in `$excel_row`, and you can use `array_except` then anything should be fine

Comment: No it does not work as soon as an empty $excel_row[$key] is found it terminates the loop. for example if key 5 is null and key 7 is not null then  $data has only 5 keys.

Comment: i put the `dd` as example, that an empty field is found, so it is not going fine

Answer (score 0):

```
class UsersImport implements ToModel, WithUpserts
{
    /**
     * @return string|array
     */
    public function uniqueBy()
    {
        return 'email';
    }
    if (!isset($row[0])) {
        return null;
    }

    return new User([
        'name' => $row[0],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you improve your answer by describing what the code does?